# Mybatis, BoneCP, Spring: SQLBuilder Memory leak issue in Tomcat 7.0.*

Tags: spring, memory, memory-leaks, mybatis, bonecp

I'm working on a project using Spring, Mybatis and BoneCP.

Every time I stop Tomcat server, I observe the following mem leak issues:

```
Dec 23, 2012 5:20:21 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/project] appears to have started a thread named [com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 23, 2012 5:20:21 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/project] appears to have started a thread named [Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to /127.0.0.1:11211}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 23, 2012 5:20:21 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/project] appears to have started a thread named [transcoder-1-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 23, 2012 5:20:21 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/project] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@386602aa]) and a value of type [org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.SqlBuilder.SQL] (value [org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.SqlBuilder$SQL@313903d3]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 23, 2012 5:20:21 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/project] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [jsr166y.ThreadLocalRandom$1] (value [jsr166y.ThreadLocalRandom$1@162a2ae4]) and a value of type [jsr166y.ThreadLocalRandom] (value [jsr166y.ThreadLocalRandom@2a65ea1a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

The number of SqlBuilder seems increase for every database access. Your help/comment is very appreciated.

Here are my configurations:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.firefly</groupId>
    <artifactId>ArcaneAeon</artifactId>
    <name>project</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MyBatis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Connection Pooling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp-spring</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.caches</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-memcached</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>    



        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-generator-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Denvironment="development"</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo message="Copying war package to server....."/>
                                <scp
                                    file="....."
                                    todir="....."
                                    password="....." trust="true" />
                                <echo message="Complete copying war package to server....."/>

                                <echo message="Executing deploy script on server...."/>
                                <sshexec
                                    username="....."
                                    password="....."
                                    host="....."
                                    trust="true"
                                    command="......"/>
                                <echo message="Finish deploying...."/>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <context:annotation-config /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.firefly.lcgame" />

    <!-- Load Properties Files -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*-${environment}.properties"/>

    <!-- Spring Data Redis -->
    <bean id="connectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
        <property name="hostName" value="${redis.host}" />
        <property name="port" value="${redis.port}" />
        <property name="password" value="${redis.pass}" />
        <property name="usePool" value="${redis.pooling}" />
        <property name="poolConfig" ref="jedisPoolConfig" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
        <property name="maxActive" value="${redis.maxActive}" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="${redis.minIdle}" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="${redis.testOnBorrow}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
        p:connection-factory-ref="connectionFactory" />

    <!-- BoneCP configuration -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="${boneCP.idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes}"/>
        <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="${boneCP.idleMaxAgeInMinutes}"/>
        <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="${boneCP.maxConnectionsPerPartition}"/>
        <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="${boneCP.minConnectionsPerPartition}"/>
        <property name="partitionCount" value="${boneCP.partitionCount}"/>
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${boneCP.acquireIncrement}"/>
        <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="${boneCP.statementsCacheSize}"/>
        <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="${boneCP.releaseHelperThreads}"/>
        <property name="lazyInit" value="true"/>
        <property name="maxConnectionAgeInSeconds" value="${boneCP.maxConnectionAgeInSeconds}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <!-- <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml" /> -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mappers" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.firefly.lcgame.dao" />
        <!-- <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory" /> -->
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
                <!-- <ref bean="marshallingConverter" />
                <ref bean="atomConverter" /> -->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jsonConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver"/>

    <!-- localization -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
      p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false" p:useCodeAsDefaultMessage="true" p:defaultEncoding="UTF-8">
      <description>Base message source to handle internationalization</description>
      <property name="basenames">
        <list>
          <value>classpath:localization/messages</value>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="annotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver">
      <property name="order" value="0"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="restExceptionResolver" class="com.firefly.lcgame.exceptions.handler.RestExceptionHandler">
      <property name="order" value="100"></property>
      <property name="errorResolver">
        <bean class="com.firefly.lcgame.exceptions.handler.DefaultRestErrorResolver">
          <property name="localeResolver" ref="localeResolver"></property>
          <!-- <property name="defaultMoreInfoUrl" value="mailto:support@mycompany.com"></property> -->
          <property name="exceptionMappingDefinitions">
            <map>
              <!-- 404 -->
              <entry key="com.firefly.lcgame.exceptions.InvalidAccessExeption" value="404, 1, error.invalid.access,  _exmsg"></entry>
              <!-- 500 (catch all): -->
              <entry key="Throwable" value="500, 1, error.internal, _exmsg"></entry>
            </map>
          </property>
        </bean>
      </property>
    </bean>

  <!-- Secure Rest Service Configuration -->
    <!-- <security:http create-session="never" entry-point-ref="digestEntryPoint">
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/duty/stages**" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
      <security:http-basic />
      <security:custom-filter ref="digestFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    </security:http> -->

    <security:http pattern="/login**"  security="none">
    </security:http>

    <security:http pattern="/dummy**">
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/dummy**" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
      <security:http-basic/>
    </security:http>

    <security:http pattern="/**" entry-point-ref="digestEntryPoint" >
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
      <security:custom-filter ref="digestFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    </security:http>

    <bean id="digestFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationFilter">
       <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
       <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="digestEntryPoint" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="digestEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint">
      <property name="realmName" value="Arcane Aeon Digest Secure REST-WS"/>
      <property name="key" value="0606e6c2-cee4-3259-9d3e-27d484d716b0"/>
      <property name="nonceValiditySeconds" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager>
      <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="userService" class="com.firefly.lcgame.services.CustomerUserDetailsService">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Secure Rest Service Configuration  -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```